# Python 3: read file of names, create new file with first names and last names reverse

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a noob to python and am stuck on a simple task. I looked at similar questions on stackoverflow but was not able to apply to my own problem. I have created a file with a list of names. How do I create a new file where it reads the original file (pretending that I don't know how many names are in the file) and reverses the names (people are in same order but with last name before first name). Below is my script:

```
firstname1 = "Morty"
lastname1 = "Smith"
fullname1 = firstname1 + " " + lastname1

firstname2 = "Donna"
lastname2 = "Gueterman"
fullname2 = firstname2 + " " + lastname2

firstname3 = "Beth"
lastname3 = "Smith"
fullname3 = firstname3 + " " + lastname3

firstname4 = "Rick"
lastname4 = "Sanchez"
fullname4 = firstname4 + " " + lastname4

firstname5 = "Little"
lastname5 = "Dipper"
fullname5 = firstname5 + " " + lastname5

formal_names = fullname1,fullname2,fullname3,fullname4,fullname5

f = open("names_normal.txt","w")
f.write("%s " % (formal_names, ))
f.close()

def reverse_list(lst):
    new = []
    count = len(lst)-1
    while count >=0:
        new.append(lst[count])
        count -= 1
    return new

x = reverse_list(formal_names)

n = open("names_new.txt","w")
n.write("%s " % (x, ))
n.close()
```

These are my results:

1st file:
    ('Morty Smith', 'Donna Gueterman', 'Beth Smith', 'Rick Sanchez', 
    'Little Dipper')

2nd file: ('Little Dipper', 'Rick Sanchez', 'Beth Smith', 'Donna Gueterman', 'Morty Smith')

What I want: ('Smith Morty', 'Gueterman Donna', 'Smith Beth', 'Sanchez Rick', 'Dipper Little')

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you so much!

Comment: Have you by any chance tried: `lastnameX + " " + firstnameX`? Like to reverse the order of the concatenation...

Comment: Hi! Yes, so I did that in my original. I guess what I am trying to accomplish is for the command to be able to look into a file without knowing anything, but that there are names in there. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

```
def reverse_list(lst):
        new = []
        for name in lst:
                temp = name.split(" ")
                new += [temp[1]+" "+temp[0]]
```

You're just changing order of words in the array, you should change order of the name and surname with splitting from space.

Answer (score 0):

```
def reverse_name(name):
    # Try to fill here and update if doesn't work

def reverse_list(lst):
    new = []
    for name in lst:
       new.append(reverse_name(name))
    return new
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your willingness to help! In define reverse_name, is this where I would write my syntax defining each person in the list?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I attacked this problem. It's probably best to put this in a function as mentioned above.

```
firstname1 = "Morty"
lastname1 = "Smith"
fullname1 = firstname1 + " " + lastname1
firstname2 = "Donna"
lastname2 = "Gueterman"
fullname2 = firstname2 + " " + lastname2
firstname3 = "Beth"
lastname3 = "Smith"
fullname3 = firstname3 + " " + lastname3
firstname4 = "Rick"
lastname4 = "Sanchez"
fullname4 = firstname4 + " " + lastname4
firstname5 = "Little"
lastname5 = "Dipper"
fullname5 = firstname5 + " " + lastname5
formal_names = [fullname1,fullname2,fullname3,fullname4,fullname5]

reversed = []
for i in range(0, (len(formal_names))):
    rev = formal_names[i].split()
    rev_name = rev[1] + ' ' + rev[0]
    reversed.append(rev_name)
print(reversed)
['Smith Morty', 'Gueterman Donna', 'Smith Beth', 'Sanchez Rick', 'Dipper Little']
```

now you just write the list to a file

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as file:
    for name in reversed:
        file.write(name)
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for being willing to help! I am trying to follow this; when I plug in the reversed = [] section. I get the following:

Comment: [1 2 3]
[[1, 2, 3] [4, 5, 6, 7] [8, 4, 5, 6]]
[ 0  2  4  6  8 10]
[[ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]]
[[ 1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.]]

Comment: Any idea why it is spitting out integers rather than the text?

Comment: Huh, that's strange. I made an edit to the write section to use a different variable. It might be that the same variable from the loop above is still in play. Try this and let me know if this helps. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You are complicating matters using separate variables for each person's name. In Python the better way of handling this is to use one of python's data structures, in this case a `list` with each name contained in a `tuple`. The advantage of doing this is that you can iterate over the list and refer to parts of the name by position, for example: `names[0][1]` for "Smith".

```
names = [("Morty","Smith"),
         ("Donna","Gueterman"),
         ("Beth","Smith"),
         ("Rick","Sanchez"),
         ("Little","Dipper")]
```

Or, if you wish you can used a `namedtuple` to make things clear, especially if you add other data items for each person.

```
import collections
Person = collections.namedtuple('Person', 'first last')
names = [Person("Morty","Smith"),
         Person("Donna","Gueterman"),
         Person("Beth","Smith"),
         Person("Rick","Sanchez"),
         Person("Little","Dipper")]
```

The output can then be created with a list comprehension :

```
normal = ", ".join([name.first + " " + name.last for name in names])
reversed = "; ".join([name.last + ", " + name.first for name in names])
print(normal)
print(reversed)
```

You can alter the punctuation : the first string `", "` is between names, the second string `" "` is between words. Then, use the method suggested in earlier answers to store the strings in a file.

(I would advise using punctuation between last and first otherwise you can run into problems with names like "Alan Simon".)

Comment: This is fantastic. I have not used a namedtuple yet, but it has now caught my attention. Will be looking this up to understand it better. Thank you for your help!